# Create a new record in another model with a condition in Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this model

```
class crm_claim(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.claim'

    needs_credit_note = fields.Boolean(string="Needs Credit Note?")
    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Partner')
```

I need to create a function that, when `needs_credit_note == True`,creates a new record con `account.invoice` with the same `partner_id`, and when `needs_credit_note == False`, delete this record. This is what I did but is not working yet.

```
@api.depends("needs_credit_note")
def create(self, vals):
    self.ensure_one()
    if self.needs_credit_note:
        self.env['account.invoice'].create({
            'partner_id': self.partner_id.id,
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, `self` is an empty record set, and `self.needs_credit_note` will be evaluated to `False`. You need to call `super` or get the values from `vals`.

The partner field should be required when the `needs_credit_note` field value is set

***Example:***

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    record = super(crm_claim, self).create(vals)
    if record.needs_credit_note:
        self.env['account.invoice'].create({
            'partner_id': record.partner_id.id,
        })
    return record
```

Probably, you will need to provide the required fields to create the invoice record